# Append to Multiple RTF file in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have list string with respective RTF string ,then how can I append in `RichTextBox` using iteration?

```
this.PreviewRichText.Text = string.Empty;
for (int x = 0; x < entriesList.Count; x++) 
{
    this.PreviewRichText.AppendText(entriesList[x].Excerpt); 
    this.PreviewRichText.Rtf = entriesList[x].ExcerptRtf; 
    _summarycomment += entriesList[x].ReReviewComment ; 
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample list of RTF strings?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rtfContents` is a list of strings which are your rtf file contents, you can use such code:

```
List<string> rtfContents = new List<string>(); //Load it from somewhere 
richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
foreach (string rtf in rtfContents)
{
    richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
    richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = rtf;
}
```

The point is, in each round of loop, move the selection to the end of `RichTextBox` and then set `SelectedRtf` to the content which you want to append.

You can create a method like this:

```
public void AppendRtf(RichtextBox rtb, string rtf)
{
    rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength, 0);
    rtb.SelectedRtf = rtf;
}
```